# Sharepoint 2013 and VisualStudio 2012 tools to make deployment faster

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I have some question about deployment, is there any way to make it faster? I have sharepoint 2013 in cloud, i am developing app-hosted application, and every time i have to wait some about 4/5 minutes. Is there any way, any tool to make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have a look here: http://blog.mastykarz.nl/quickly-deploying-sharepoint-2013-projects-mavention-quick-deploy/

It will only build your project, move the assembly to GAC and reset the App Pool.